# How to add the text in String passed from another activity and show the resulting text in Textview

Tags: java, android

I am passing value from `Activity A` to `Activity B`. It works fine.

For Example, if I pass String `"Harvey Brown"`, Then in next activity it also shows `"Harvey Brown"`.

But I would also like to add `"Author: "` text before `"Harvey Brown"` and show the sum result in `TextView` such that now instead of only 
`"Harvey Brown"`.

It will show

```
Author:Harvey Brown
```

for every intent.

> Here is the code, I'm using to pass String value:

```
  intent.putExtra("Title",mData.get(position).getTitle());
```

> and in next activity I received value by

```
Intent intent = getIntent();


    String author_name = intent.getExtras().getString("author_name");
```

> and I set the value accordingly as

```
 author_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author_nameid);
 author_name.setText(author_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a 'Author:' Prefix like below -

```
author_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author_nameid); 
author_name.setText("Author: " + author_name);
```

Comment: This answer works in only Activity B, no doubt it's correct, but my answer can work whenever you pass the author to. it will automatically assign Author in any activity you need.. Consider my answer if you need the word "Author" dynamically.

Comment: @BirNepali happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Just change this line:

```
intent.putExtra("Title",mData.get(position).getTitle());
```

To

```
intent.putExtra("Title", "Author: " + mData.get(position).getTitle());
```

You will get your desired result.